# Excel AdvanceFilter vba copyToRange only working for topmost Row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, advanced-filter

I have a sheet "RM" in a workbook, and another sheet "ST" in the same workbook. "RM" has Table2 and "ST" has Table 3

I use the following code to copy from RM to another sheet "Andy"
refName is a Criteria in "Andy" and topRowName is the string "Andy!B1:M1"

```
Sheets("RM").Range("Table2[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range(refName), CopyToRange:=Range(topRowName), Unique:= _
        False
```

So far so good, everything works
Now I want to copy from "ST" also to "Andy" but paste it a few rows below "topRowName" so that it doesn't overwrite so I do an offset

```
Sheets("ST").Range("Table3[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range(refName), CopyToRange:=Range(topRowName).Offset(5), Unique:= _
        False
```

but it throws a 1004 Error "Extract Range has a missing or invalid field name"

I tried to hardcode the values in the Range like this

```
Sheets("RM").Range("Table2[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range(refName), CopyToRange:=Range(Andy!B5:M5), Unique:= _
        False
```

But it still doesn't work. Is it because there is a table in the paste location? i tried to resize the table so that it doesn't clash with the new paste but its not helping. Any help appreciated

Comment: Check your worksheet definitions. How is the tab of Range(refName) defined? Can the CriteriaRange be on any worksheet (I don't know)? How is Range(topRowName) defined? `Range(Andy!B5:M5)` is wrong syntax. Tables2 and Table3 might be constructed differently. Try the tables' range names in place of [#All]. Finally, try to run the second filter independent from the first. If both work independently but not together the problem would be different.

Comment: This may be one of the few times where `Activate` is required.  With the `Advanced Filter CopyToRange` method, the worksheet **TO** which you are copying must be the `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I found the answer to the reason why this was happening. I needed to clear out contents of the place I'm pasting to. Apparently Excel doesn't like to copy contents to a range if there is something already present, particularly a ListObject like a table. I assumed that it would just write on top of it.